Basic identity for Cayley's theorem proof
I was studying graph theory when a question came to my mind.
The proof of Cayley's theorem (as in Wilson's "Introduction to graph theory", p. 69) is somehow clear, I just can't realise why the last equality holds (which should be easy since it's not explained anywhere). WolframAlpha confirms its validity as well. It's the following:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-1)^{-k+n-1}\binom{n-2}{k-1} = n^{n-2} $$
The text gives the intermediate passage $\{(n-1)+1\}^{n-2}$. Can anyone enlighten me?

The intermediate passage is a hint that you should recognise the left-hand side expression as an instance of the binomial theorem.

Okay, now it's clear. Thank you.

This looks like a pretty straightforward application of the binomial theorem. For a natural number $N$, we have
$$
    \sum_{i=0}^N \binom{N}{i} x^{N-i}y^i = (x+y)^N
$$
If we set $N=n-2$, $x=n-1$, and $y=1$, we get
$$
    \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{i} (n-1)^{n-2-i} \cdot 1^i = ((n-1)+1)^{n-2} = n^{n-2}
$$
Now reindex the sum by setting $k=i+1$. We get
$$
    n^{n-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-2}{k-1}(n-1)^{n-2-(k-1)}
    = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-2}{k-1}(n-1)^{-k+n-1}
$$
